# Elasticsearch, how to check if my dynamic mapping works?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm providing a default mapping dynamic template at index creation in elasticsearch and wanted to check if it works as expected. Got me stumped, how can I verify if it works?
(Working with ES 2.2.2)

```
"mappings": {
    "_default_": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "no_date_detection": {
                    "match_mapping_type": "string",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "date_detection": false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "language_de": {
                    "match_mapping_type": "*",
                    "match": "*_de",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "german"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "language_es": {
                    "match":              "*_es",
                    "match_mapping_type": "*",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type":           "string",
                        "analyzer":       "spanish"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "language_en": {
                    "match":              "*_en",
                    "match_mapping_type": "*",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type":           "string",
                        "analyzer":       "english"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It's pretty straightforward, like in the examples provided in the documentation.

GETting the mapping shows that the dynamic templates are handed down to new types

```
 "testobject": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
       {
          "no_date_detection": {
             "mapping": {
                "type": "string",
                "date_detection": false
             },
             "match_mapping_type": "string"
          }
       },
       {
          "language_de": {
       ...
```

But when I create an object with new fields like
"description_en": "some english text"
and GET the mapping it just shows

```
       "description_en": {
          "type": "string"
       }
```

Shouldn't this have
"analyzer": "english"
in it?

What did I do wrong, and if my dynamic mapping is correct, how can I verify that it gets applied?

Thanks in advance /Carsten

---

As my question "how can I verify that it gets applied?" seems unclear, I try to simplify:

1. I create an index with *default* dynamic mapping.
2. I create a type "testobject".
3. "GET /myindex/testobject/_mappings" verifies that, as expected, the dynamic templates are handed down to the type.
4. I create a new field in an object of type testobject.
5. "GET /myindex/testobject/_mappings" shows the new field but *without* say '"date_detection": false'. It shows it just as a simple string (see above).

How can I verify if/that the dynamic template got applied to a newly created field?

---

Simplified example:

```
PUT /myindex
{
    "mappings": { 
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "no_date_detection": {
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "date_detection": false
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


PUT /myindex/gardeners/1
{
    "name": "gary"
}

GET /myindex/_mapping

{
   "myindex": {
      "mappings": {
         "gardeners": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
               {
                  "no_date_detection": {
                     "mapping": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "date_detection": false
                     },
                     "match_mapping_type": "string"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "properties": {
               "name": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         },
         "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
               {
                  "no_date_detection": {
                     "mapping": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "date_detection": false
                     },
                     "match_mapping_type": "string"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The mapping for my new field "name"

```
"properties": {
    "name": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

doen't contain
`"date_detection": false`
Why doesn't it get handed down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error in my assumption: `"date_detection": false` doesn't work that way with dynamic_templates.

You have to specify the date_detection directly on the mapping (not at the level of a specific type).
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html

If you want this to get automatically added to new indices, you can use index templates.

Thanks to Yannick for the hint (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/mappings--default--dynamic-templates-doesnt-show-up-in-resulting-mapping/59030)

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic templates are checked in the order they are defined and the first one that matches, that's the one that gets applied.

In your case `no_date_detection` template matches your field `description_en` because it's a `string`.

If you want that field to be used with the `english` analyzer, then you need to change the order of the templates:

```
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "language_de": {
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "match": "*_de",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "german"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "language_es": {
            "match": "*_es",
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "spanish"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "language_en": {
            "match": "*_en",
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "english"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "no_date_detection": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "date_detection": false
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: That is true, yes, But it doesn't answer my question why neither rule shows up when I GET.._mapping afterwards. How can I check / verify which rule(s) is/are applied?

Comment: What do you mean `neither rule shows up`? The mapping of the fields are the proof your rules were applied or not. And, also, in the mapping of the index/type (the mapping automatically created for your type if it didn't exist) you will see the dynamic templates there defined in the `dynamic_templates` section.

Comment: Ok, I hear you, but I can not see how my question can be ambigous? (Unless im totally off the rails...) I try to enhance my question (see above).

Comment: The only way to see if your mapping applied or not is to check the mapping of your new fields. If they do have the intended config from your templates, then the mapping succeeded.

Comment: Ok, so it should show up with "GET /myindex/testobject/_mapping" but it doesn't, as my snippets show. Is there something wrong with the syntax of my dynamic_mapping? Why doesn't it get applied?

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear in my answer: the order of your templates matters....